# Design Grapecity Active Reports inside Angular Application

Tags: .net, angular, activereports, grapecity

I want to completely move an existing application written in .NET (which also includes support to design Active Reports) to Angular. I am not sure about the feasibility of using feature of design active reports to Angular application. Viewing reports can certainly be done as per my investigation, could someone help in designing active reports in Angular or any alternative solution if this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ActiveReports 13 Web Designer in an Angular application with full framework back-end.  We also have samples that use our JavaScript report Viewer (JSViewer) with an Angular 7 application that uses an ASP.NET FW back-end.  These samples are included when you download ActiveReports, which you can download from our website here:https://www.grapecity.com/download/activereports

Also, here are some resources that provide information on our Web Designer and JSViewer:
https://help.grapecity.com/activereports/webhelp/AR13/webframe.html#JSViewer_Angular(Core).html
https://help.grapecity.com/activereports/webhelp/AR13/webframe.html#ViewingreportsusingJSViewer.html
https://help.grapecity.com/activereports/webhelp/AR13/webframe.html#Web%20Designer_MVC(Core).html
https://help.grapecity.com/activereports/webhelp/AR13/webframe.html#HowToCreateaSimpleWebDesignerSample.html
https://help.grapecity.com/activereports/webhelp/AR13/webframe.html#ActiveReportsWebDesigner.html

If you have any more questions or would like additional support, feel free to create a support ticket and our engineers will happily assist you!
https://www.grapecity.com/support/contact

Best Regards,
GrapeCity Support Team